# Cambiar propiedades de Servicio desde código

Tags: c#, servicio

quiero cambiar las propiedades de un servicio que tengo corriendo en mi ordenador desde una aplicación en c#.

Lo que quiero hacer es, teniendo un servicio instalado ya, cambiar sus propiedades de Tipo de Inicio a Automático (inicio retrasado) y sus opciones de recuperación ( el primer y segundo error) que se reinicie el servicio.

He visto que al hacer esto:

```
ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
//serviceInstaller.DelayedAutoStart //No me deja utilizar esta propiedad para el automático retrasado
```

Le puedes indicar que lo establezca a automático, pero no a inicio retrasado.

Para instalar este servicio lo hago con la utilidad InstallUtil a través de:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("InstallUtil ...");
```

Comment: podrías intentarlo con el evento del Projectinstaller AfterInstall, invocar directamente al SC con los parametros que tu quieras

Comment: Con sc start = delayed-auto veo que puedo arrancar el servicio de modo automático retrasado, gracias por esto @miguel. Lo que no veo es como indicar que ante el primer y segundo error se reinicie el servicio

Comment: entonces sería con SC failure, aquí está la documentacón https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Le hecho un ojo pero antes de meterme con ello ya veo que tiene buena pinta, gracias @miguel!!! =)

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta si quieres y te lo marco como respuesta válida creo que se llama

Comment: Añado la respuesta por si puede servir a alguien más

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo llamas usando el comando `sc start = delayed-auto` puedes arrancar el servicio de manera automática y retraso.

Y para el control de las opciones de los fallo tendrás que usar el comando
`SC failure` con el cual podrás establecer las propiedades en caso de fallo.

La documentación la puedes encontrar [aquí](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019(v=ws.11).aspx).

Todo esto lo podrías llamar desde el evento `AfterInstall` del `ProjectInstaller` invocando directamente al CMD con los comandos necesarios.

Comment: Para establecer que se reinicie la primera y segunda vez si hay un fallo es con la línea siguiente: sc failure nombre_de_servicio reboot= "Error" reset= 3600 actions= restart/5000/restart/5000//